# Implement MRU cache replacement algorithm

Tags: algorithm, caching, data-structures

The often recommended way to implement an LRU cache replacement algorithm in software is to store cache items in order of access inside a doubly-linked list. If we assume that the most-recently-used element is stored at the head position and the least-recently-used element is stored at the tail, when we fill up the cache we make room for the new element by evicting the tail element.

Is there a more efficient way of implementing an MRU cache replacement algorithm than the technique described above but instead of evicting the head element you evict the tail element?

Comment: Are you asking for a different technique or an evaluation of the alternative technique you describe?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is whether there's a more efficient way to evict the MRU element compared to what amounts to the mirroring of the technique for evicting the LRU element. Is evicting the MRU element inherently easier than evicting the LRU element or is it the same?

Of course I'm open to alternative techniques provided it's true MRU and not an approximation.

Comment: The runtime cost of maintaining a doubly-linked list is cheap. More efficient would depend on the metric (e.g. space, access costs). Often being faster is by making an approximation, e.g. MRU evicts recent items so those could be kept in an access window whereas LRU requires discovering the oldest items. Since MRU is only better in certain workloads, optimizing for it directly isn't worthwhile compared to choosing a better eviction policy.

Comment: @DavidO'Loughlin Did you consider the [Splay tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree)? The amortized cost of the operations is `O(log(n))`, although the actual cost of an operation can be high.